# Magento 2 Plugin around Shipping collectRates

Tags: magento2, plugin

I could use a little guidance on writing a plugin for the *Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates* function. I have properly added the plugin to the di.xml and it's processing the around code. The trouble is, I'm getting an ObjectManager exception when running the proceed callback. At this point in the development of the plugin, I'm just trying to get the proceed to work, then I can add in the other features to my plugin.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**Magento Version:** 2.1.6

**Exception Message**
Notice: Undefined index: instance in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 112

**Plugin Class**

```
class ShippingPlugin {

  protected $shippingDataBuilder = null;

  protected $overrideFactory = null;

  protected $logger = null;

  public function __construct(
      Builder $shippingDataBuilder,
      Factory $overrideFactory,
      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->shippingDataBuilder = $shippingDataBuilder;
    $this->overrideFactory = $overrideFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }



  public function aroundCollectRates(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, callable $proceed, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $rateRequest){


    try {
        $results = $proceed($rateRequest);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        $this->logger->error($e->getTraceAsString());
    }

    return $results;
   }
 }
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin name="PluginName" type="\Company\Module\Plugin\ShippingPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Exception Stack Trace**
*My Plugin around function is line #21 in the trace*

```
main.ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: instance in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 112 [] []
main.ERROR: #0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(112): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/httpd/company...', 112, Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'Magento\\Directo...')
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Directo...', Array, Array)
#3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Directo...')
#4 vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(475): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Directo...')
#5 vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(214): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->_getResource()
#6 vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Country.php(72): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->_init('Magento\\Directo...')
#7 vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(193): Magento\Directory\Model\Country->_construct()
#8 vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Country.php(61): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Model\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Registry), NULL, NULL, Array)
#9 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Directory\Model\Country->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Model\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Registry), Object(Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists), Object(Magento\Directory\Model\Country\FormatFactory), Object(Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory), NULL, NULL, Array)
#10 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Directo...', Array)
#11 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Directo...', Array)
#12 vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/CountryFactory.php(37): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Directo...', Array, false)
#13 vendor/magento/module-ups/Model/Carrier.php(270): Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory->create()
#14 vendor/magento/module-ups/Model/Carrier.php(204): Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier->setRequest(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#15 vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(293): Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#16 vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates('ups', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#17 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#18 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callParent('collectRates', Array)
#19 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'collectRates', Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Array, 'ProgrammaticShi...')
#20 app/code/Company/Module/Plugin/ProgrammaticShipping.php(67): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#21 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Company\Module\Plugin\ProgrammaticShipping->aroundCollectRates(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#22 var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callPlugins('collectRates', Array, Array)
#23 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(995): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#24 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(936): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()
#25 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(161): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates()
#26 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php(265): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping->collect(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total))
#27 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(273): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#28 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(213): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->getShippingMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Array)
#29 vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestShippingMethodManagement.php(103): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress(173156, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#30 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress('9e74658791eb1f4...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#31 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#33 var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#36 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Answer (score 2):

You done a silly mistake

`Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject`

Should be

`\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject`

As **First slash** is missing that  `$subject`does not get object of  anby class.

Change in that  class  then

- Delete var/generation
- FLush Cache

Comment: Amit, thanks for the response. Since the code was throwing the exception in the function I added a logging line to get the class name for confirmation. The get_class($subject); code is returning "Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor". I wish it was a silly mistake and I could move on but unfortunately, I'm getting the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was indeed a silly mistake but the mistake was in another class. The issue came from another class where I had used the constructor dependency injection to inject the ObjectManager. Once I fixed that, the collectRates around method worked like a champ.

So, for anybody else getting an exception in AbstractFactory.php, make sure you have not injected the ObjectManager.